# Empty Char in Where Clause?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have the following table:

```
  CREATE TABLE SOAUDIT
  (SOU_USER CHAR(8 BYTE), 
   SOU_ORDREF CHAR(8 BYTE),
   SOU_TYPE CHAR(1 BYTE), 
   SOU_DESC CHAR(50 BYTE))
```

There is a unique index defined on the first three columns (but no primary key, which is something we have no control over).

And in the table there are some records:

```
| SOU_USER | SOU_ORDREF | SOU_TYPE | SOU_DESC         |
|----------|------------|----------|------------------|
| proust   |            | S        | recherche        |
| joyce    | 12345678   | S        | pelurious        |
| orwell   | 19841984   | T        | doubleplusungood |
| camus    | 34598798   | P        | peiner           |
```

On closer inspection it appears that the value in SOU_ORDREF for user 'proust' is an empty char string of 8 characters.

Now, what I need to be able to do is to query this table based on their unique values (which I will receive from a SQL Server database (just to complicate matters nicely). In the case of SOU_ORDREF the search value will be a blank field:

```
SELECT * 
FROM SOAUDIT 
WHERE (SOU_USER, TRIM(SOU_ORDREF), SOU_TYPE)
IN (('proust', null, 'S'))
```

This doesn't return the record I am looking for.

When I rewrite the query as following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM SOAUDIT 
WHERE (SOU_USER, SOU_TYPE)
IN (('proust', 'S'))
AND TRIM(sou_ordref) is null
```

Then I *do* get the desired record.

However, I want to be able to pass in more than one record into the `WHERE` clause so the second version doesn't really help.

Comment: An empty char string of 8 characters is not null... Have you tried `'        '` (8 spaces)?

Comment: Yes, I did. It worked. However, in production the records that I will get to filter with will have empty strings for these sort of values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle -- by default -- treats empty strings and `NULL` as the same thing.

This can cause awkward behavior, because comparisons to `NULL` almost never return true.  So a simple expression such as `where sou_ordref = ''` never returns true, because it is equivalent to `where sou_ordref = NULL`.

Here is one workaround:

```
SELECT * 
FROM SOAUDIT 
WHERE (SOU_USER, COALESCE(TRIM(SOU_ORDREF), ' '), SOU_TYPE) IN
          ( ('proust', ' ', 'S') )
```

Note that this replaces the empty string (`NULL`) with a space.  It then compares the results to a space.

Comment: Thanks - that worked for me, and a helpful explanation to boot.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
SELECT * 
FROM test 
WHERE SOU_USER = 'proust'
AND SOU_TYPE = 'S' 
AND TRIM(sou_ordref) = ''
```

Since an empty char is different than `NULL`

Comment: In this case I want to be able to use more than one record as the search criteria.